# Why 'have' instead of 'had'?

Tags: usage

I can't understand why the author used '***have***' instead of '***had***', though the context clearly indicate the past?

> It was only 50 years ago that humanity began to extend its presence
> into space — first with robots, then with animals and finally with
> humans. This tentative expansion of our species towards other worlds
> has been made possible by the development of technology, which has
> finally started to reach a level that can complement and support our
> imagination and desire for exploration. However, considering the size
> of the universe and the growing number of promising sites on many
> worlds where life might quite like to snuggle up, the search has
> barely begun. When we finally find life on another world — and we will
> — it will be one of the most significant cultural events in human
> history, having a profound impact on the question of our origins. It
> is not surprising, therefore, to find that such possibilities have
> been discussed by every human civilisation and culture, primitive or
> advanced, as far back as we ***have*** written records. Even before
> these thoughts were given a name, such extraterrestrial wonderings
> found their outlet through myths, cave paintings, fictional
> literature, music and poetry, then later through films and TV
> shows.

[Goldilocks and the Water Bears: The Search for Life in the Universe](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=wTQgDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=that%20such%20possibilities%20have%20been%20discussed%20by%20every%20human%20civilisation%20and%20culture,%20primitive%20or%20advanced,%20as%20far%20back%20as%20we%20have%20written%20records.%20Even%20before%20these%20thoughts%20were%20given%20a%20name,%20such%20extraterrestrial%20wonderings%20found&source=bl&ots=7XYKPeRdrz&sig=ACfU3U1F92_aBLVLufQKh86ieViwVXJV3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit0IrPwLbvAhXjLX0KHfubBP8Q6AEwAHoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=that%20such%20possibilities%20have%20been%20discussed%20by%20every%20human%20civilisation%20and%20culture%2C%20primitive%20or%20advanced%2C%20as%20far%20back%20as%20we%20have%20written%20records.%20Even%20before%20these%20thoughts%20were%20given%20a%20name%2C%20such%20extraterrestrial%20wonderings%20found&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

The word `have` in this case indicates that this clause, `we have written records`, is in the present tense. It is referring to `written records` which `we` currently `have` and which still exist. Perhaps a more clear wording would be:

> ...**from** as far back as we **still** have written records.

Feel free to reply if you still don't understand.

Comment: Clearly understood. Thank you, Eddie Kal.